# Reading in a formatted line to populate an array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to read a certain number of lines from a txt file into an array using python. The txt file is formatted by FORTRAN with 3 integers, two of 3 character length, and one of 2 character length (i.e. 24238 8. where the values are 24,238, 8). There are 7 3 integer 'groups' per line. Below is 8 lines of the txt file.

```
24238 8. 27237 8. 38 82 6. 38 96 6. 39 76 6. 39 77 6. 39 78 6.BARR  1
39 79 6. 39 80 6. 39 81 6. 39 82 6. 39 84 6. 39 85 6. 39 86 6.BARR  2
39 88 8. 39 89 8. 39 9010. 39 91 7. 39 92 7. 39 93 5. 39 96 6.BARR  3
39 9710. 39 9810. 39 9910. 3910010. 3910113. 3910212. 3910312.BARR  4
3910412. 3910512. 40 72 6. 40 73 6. 40 74 6. 40 75 6. 40 76 6.BARR  5
40 80 9. 40 8110. 40 8212. 40 8312. 40 84 8. 4010512. 4010612.BARR  6
40107 9. 40108 9. 40109 9. 41 70 6. 41 71 6. 41 77 6. 41 78 6.BARR  7
41 79 8. 41 80 8. 4110910. 41110 6. 41111 6. 41184 8. 42 73 2.BARR  8
```

I do not want to worry about the BARR 1, etc. at the end of each line either, it can just be ignored. I have created an array of initial values that I wish to fill with values from the txt file.

```
import numpy as np
basin = open("il3_barrier","r")
zbm = np.full((171,251),-300)
```

What I want is for the 3rd value in the 'group' of three to populate the array based on the first and second value. For example, I want the value 8 to occupy the array at location 24, 238 and so on.

I am using a piece of code from another answer on stackoverflow. But I am not certain how to loop through lines using it.

```
def slices(s, *args):
    position = 0
    for length in args:
        yield s[position:position + length]
        position += length
```

For this example with looking at just 8 lines, I was going to try something that looks like this:

```
for h in range(0,8): 
    tempLine = basin.readline()
    for k in range(0,7):
        inw,jnw,hw = list(slices(tempLine,3,3,2))
        inw = int(inw)
        jnw = int(jnw)
        zbm [inw,jnw] = hw
```

This just returns the first group of values for each line and doesn't loop through the entire line. Is there a way to get it to loop through each group of numbers in a single line? Or maybe there is a way to do it another way?

Comment: what is desired output for fist line? How big should be the output array?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi it's 7 different points. So, the first line I have as: ```24238 8. 27237 8. 38 82 6. 38 96 6. 39 76 6. 39 77 6. 39 78 6.BARR  1``` So I need new values in the array zbm for all 7 of these points. I need an 8 for (24,238), an 8 for (27,237), a 6 for (38,82), a 6 for (38,96), a 6 for (39,76) a 6 for (39,77) a 6 for (39,78). Is that what you are asking? Because right now it is only writing an 8 for (24,238).

Comment: ok i try to solve this

Comment: What is to determine that, for example, the coordinate for the first entry is `(24, 238)` and not `(242, 38)`? The spaces clear that up for the smaller coords, but not for larger ones

Comment: @C.Nivs I just look in the array to see if the correct value is there or not. There is a space before the 24, so it counts the space as one of the 3 characters.

Comment: `genfromtxt` allows the `delimiter` to be a list of integers giving the width of each field.  You might also want to use `usecols` to skip the `BARR` column.  Done right the result should be a 2d array of dtype float.  Or with `dtype=None`, a structured array with a mix of integer and float fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here You go =^..^=

Short descriptions in code.

```
import numpy as np

# load raw data
raw_data = []
with open('raw_data.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    for item in data:
        raw_data.append(item.strip())

# collect coordinates data
coordinates_data = []
for item in raw_data:
    for i in range(0, 63, 9):
        coordinates_data.append((item[0+i:2+i].strip(), item[2+i:5+i].strip(), item[6+i:7+i].strip().replace('.', '')))

# get values for array size
max_x = 0
max_y = 0
for item in coordinates_data:
    if max_x < int(item[0]):
        max_x = int(item[0])
    if max_y < int(item[1]):
        max_y = int(item[1])

# create empty array
final_array = np.zeros((max_x+1, max_y+1))

# load data into array
for item in coordinates_data:
    final_array[int(item[0]), int(item[1])] = int(item[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the field width version of `delimiter` I can load the first two groups of numbers using `genfromtxt`  (`txt` is a multiline paste of your file sample):

```
In [221]: dels = [2,3,3, 3,3,3]; cols=[0,1,2,3,4,5]                                                    
In [222]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=dels, usecols=cols, dtype=float)                   
Out[222]: 
array([[ 24., 238.,   8.,  27., 237.,   8.],
       [ 39.,  79.,   6.,  39.,  80.,   6.],
       [ 39.,  88.,   8.,  39.,  89.,   8.],
       [ 39.,  97.,  10.,  39.,  98.,  10.],
       [ 39., 104.,  12.,  39., 105.,  12.],
       [ 40.,  80.,   9.,  40.,  81.,  10.],
       [ 40., 107.,   9.,  40., 108.,   9.],
       [ 41.,  79.,   8.,  41.,  80.,   8.]])
```

I had to use `dtype` float because of the '8.' field.  I suppose I could shorten the field and skip the '.' instead.

Or if I specify a `None` type, it makes a structured array with a mix of integer and float dtype fields.

```
In [223]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=dels, usecols=cols, dtype=None)                    
Out[223]: 
array([(24, 238,  8., 27, 237,  8.), (39,  79,  6., 39,  80,  6.),
       (39,  88,  8., 39,  89,  8.), (39,  97, 10., 39,  98, 10.),
       (39, 104, 12., 39, 105, 12.), (40,  80,  9., 40,  81, 10.),
       (40, 107,  9., 40, 108,  9.), (41,  79,  8., 41,  80,  8.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<i8'), ('f4', '<i8'), ('f5', '<f8')])
```

`dels` and `cols` can be extended to handle all 7 groups.

Once you have numbers like this it should be easy to map them on to your final coordinates array.  But I assume you have that worked out already.

===

Splitting the '.' off into its own, un-used, column:

```
In [226]: dels = [2,3,2,1, 3,3,2,1]; cols=[0,1,2, 4,5,6]                                               
In [227]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=dels, usecols=cols, dtype=int)                     
Out[227]: 
array([[ 24, 238,   8,  27, 237,   8],
       [ 39,  79,   6,  39,  80,   6],
       [ 39,  88,   8,  39,  89,   8],
       [ 39,  97,  10,  39,  98,  10],
       [ 39, 104,  12,  39, 105,  12],
       [ 40,  80,   9,  40,  81,  10],
       [ 40, 107,   9,  40, 108,   9],
       [ 41,  79,   8,  41,  80,   8]])
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

```
def slices7(s,pos, *args):
    S=[]
    for length in args:
        S.append(s[pos:pos + length])
        pos += length
    return pos,S
```

Was used with,

```
for h in range(1,8):
    tempLine = basin.readline()
    pos=0
    for k in range(0,7):
        pos,AAA= list(slices7(tempLine,pos,3,3,3))
        try:
            inw = int(AAA[0])
            jnw = int(AAA[1])
            hw = float(AAA[2])
            zbm [inw,jnw] = hw
        except ValueError:
            pass
```